# How to Upload a file and save to DB using PHP, JavaScript, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

everyone..
i've problem using javascript.
i want to make CRUD using Modal(bootstrap), PHP and javascript. but unfortunatelly til now i can't upload a file and save them to database. i have 3 files (index, form, javascript, process) here is my code :

**for modal (index) :**

```
<div id="dialog-admin" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel"></h3>
</div>
<!-- tempat untuk menampilkan form admin -->
<div class="modal-body"></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Batal</button>
    <button id="simpan-admin" class="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
</div>
```

**this code for form file :**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-admin" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div> ... bla bla bla.. field.. </div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="ava">Image</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="file" id="ava" name="ava" value="<?php echo $ava ?>" required="required" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**this code for javascript :**

```
$("#simpan-admin").bind("click", function(event) {
        var url = "admin-proses.php";

        // mengambil nilai dari inputbox, textbox dan select
        var v_username = $('input:text[name=username]').val();
        var v_email = $('input:text[name=email]').val();
        var v_pass = $('input:text[name=pass]').val();
        var v_ava = $('input:file[name=ava]').val();

        // mengirimkan data ke berkas transaksi admin-proses.php untuk di proses
        $.post(url, {username: v_username, email: v_email, pass: v_pass, ava:v_ava, id: id} ,function() {
            // tampilkan data admin yang sudah di perbaharui
            // ke dalam <div id="data-admin"></div>
            $("#data-admin").load(main);

            // sembunyikan modal dialog
            $('#dialog-admin').modal('hide');

            // kembalikan judul modal dialog
            $("#myModalLabel").html("Tambah Data Admin");
        });
    });
```

**and this code for file process :**

```
require 'dbase.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$pass   = $_POST['pass'];

$imageName = $_FILES['ava']['name'];
$imageSize = $_FILES['ava']['size'];
$imageError = $_FILES['ava']['error'];


    if ($imageSize > 0 || $imageError == 0){
        $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/ava/'.$imageName);
        if ($move){
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo 'failed';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'failed to save file to DB : '.$imageError;

    }


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_admin VALUES('','$username','$email','$pass','$imageName')") or die (mysql_error());
```

could you to help me ?
thank
Regard

Comment: Have you tried debugging at every stage?

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz : yes i've, i think the error is come from javascript when i try to get file information from input file and store them to var v_ava = $('input:file[name=ava]').val();
could you to help me  ? what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

check whether the post has been done properly in jquery. do step by step debugging.Be sure of getting all input field values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should go to this link by W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

It covers all the basics of file uploading.

For Database, go through this:

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx